# Does `a developing sense` mean that the sense/idea approaches but not achieves the advanced?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, expressions

From this [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=M64sDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=Interest%20and%20advances%20in%20deep%20learning%20are%20still%20growing%20rapidly%20in%20both%20the%20computer%20vision%20and%20the%20medical%20image%20processing%20communities.%20In%20the%20computer%20vision%20community,%20there%20is%20a%20developing%20sense%20that%20the%20large%20ImageNet%20archive%20used%20for%20train-%20ing%20the%20first%20generation%20of%20deep%20lear&source=bl&ots=gNQLCvP4bh&sig=ACfU3U3Jvw9xC2RmH4KhIZS1kAgikpTYzA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk4Y3v97_jAhXxoFsKHUBkBmoQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Interest%20and%20advances%20in%20deep%20learning%20are%20still%20growing%20rapidly%20in%20both%20the%20computer%20vision%20and%20the%20medical%20image%20processing%20communities.%20In%20the%20computer%20vision%20community%2C%20there%20is%20a%20developing%20sense%20that%20the%20large%20ImageNet%20archive%20used%20for%20train-%20ing%20the%20first%20generation%20of%20deep%20lear&f=false) "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> Interest and advances in deep learning are still growing rapidly in
>   both the computer vision and the medical image processing
>   communities. In the computer vision community, there is a `developing`
>   `sense` that the large ImageNet archive used for training the first
>   generation of deep learning systems is nearing exhaustion and new,
>   larger next-generation image databases are needed to take deep
>   learning to the next level, e.g., the Visual Genome project

Comment: Thanks you. Please copy your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes "developing" means that something is currently underdeveloped and not advanced or mature. People sometimes use it that way when they talk about "developing" nations or economies. But here it just means "growing". So a "developing sense that ... XYZ...." means that the belief in XYZ is growing and becoming more respected as more people are starting to believe that XYZ is true.